# basemap contour colorbar not labeling contours correctly

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-basemap, colorbar

I have a contour plot in matplotlib basemap- negative contours dashed, positive solid. The colorbar for this field is not being drawn correctly. The tics on the colorbar are correct [-100,100] however the bar is compressed dashes that should appear uniformly spread across the range of the color bar are compressed around zero. Code is posted below

```
xlon,xlat = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

mapLineColor = [0,0,0,0.5]
panel_labels = ['(a)']

# initialize the plot
fig,ax = PP.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,8))

# initialize the map
#m = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=-120,resolution='c',ax=ax)
m = Basemap(projection='merc', ax=ax, lat_0=35, lon_0=210,
    resolution = 'h', area_thresh = 1000.0,
    llcrnrlon=90, llcrnrlat=-10,
    urcrnrlon=295, urcrnrlat=75)

# plot height contorus
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-100,vmax=100)
levels = np.arange(-100,120,20)

#create the z contour plot
clptn = m.contour(xlon, xlat, z250_nat100nat_pnw_avg, levels=levels, vmin=-100,vmax=100, latlon=True, colors='b',norm=norm)

# add an axis for the z colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([-0.025, 0.275, 0.02, 0.45])

# draw the colorbar
cb = fig.colorbar(clptn, cax=cbar_ax, label='z250 Height Anomaly [m]')
#cb.set_ticks(levels)
cb.ax.yaxis.set_ticks(levels)
cbar_ax.set_yticklabels(levels) 
cb.set_clim([-100,100])
cb.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
cb.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
```

This the output:

[image: contour colorbar fail]

What is wrong with my code that the colorbar is not spanning the full range of contours?

Answer (score 0):

I think because the levels value range is different from that of the latitude value range.

May be you can set the levels like shown below

```
levels = np.arange(np.floor(xlat.min()),np.ceil(xlat.max()))
```

Comment: Hm yeah thats true, but why would they need to be the same? The idea is to contour the z-data (z250_nat100nat_pnw_avg- max=40, min=-85) and have a contour colorbar that is symmetric and evenly spaced between [-100,100], hence my attempt to use np.arange(-100,120,20)